# C++ Winsock Socket Error: 10038 (WSAENOTSOCK)

Tags: c++, select, winsock

I have an master slave application Master running on WinXp(i7, 2.1 Ghz) and slave being a controller board. The master sends request to the slave and the slave in response send to the master the data cyclically. This data send cyclically by the slave is 1000 bytes per 0.5 msec.
When the masters makes the request to send the data, on the console an error is reported.

" Select() function error code:: 10038 ".

This is the code for `WSAENOTSOCK`.

This application is a single threaded application receiving the data from the slave.
As from the error it seems that the socket is closed before it is checked by the select function.

Can any one please point me in the direction ?

:::Source Code::::

```
int Receive()
{
    int rc;
    socklen_t cli_alen;
    struct timeval to;
    fd_set read_fd, write_fd, excep_fd;

    FD_ZERO(&write_fd);
    FD_ZERO(&excep_fd);

sock_again:
    if (!_isSocketOpen) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
    FD_SET(_sock_fd, &read_fd);
    to.tv_sec =  0;
    to.tv_usec = 0;
    cli_alen = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);

    rc = select(_sock_fd+1, &read_fd, &write_fd, &excep_fd, &to);

    if (rc == 0 )  
    {   // Timeout
        // printf("XCP Port %d : select() timded out \n", _port);
        acess = 1;
        goto sock_again;
    } 
    else if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
        // Error
        LogError("XCP: select() error %d", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(_sock_fd);
        return -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Data
        if (!FD_ISSET(_sock_fd, &read_fd)) 
        {
            LogError("XCP: select() wrong socket descr");
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            //read data
            rc = recvfrom(_sock_fd, (char *)_recvBuf, UDP_RECVBUFLEN, 0, (LPSOCKADDR)&_saddr, &cli_alen);
}
}
}
```

:::: Edited ::::

```
int CloseUdpConnection()
{
    if (closesocket(_sock_fd) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        LogError("closesocket() error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    _isSocketOpen = 0;
    LogError("successfully closed socket %s:%d", _address, _port);
    return 0;
}
```

::::: Debug Trace :::::

```
xcpApplication.exe -i 192.168.1.100 -p 5555
c
--> Connecting...
<-- Connection established
t
--> Setting daq signal list...
Sorting daq signal list...
Sorting done
<-- Daq signal list set
d
--> Configuring daq lists...
<-- Configuration done
r
--> Starting measurement...
<-- Measurement started

**_sock_fd: -448997078**
XCP: select() error 10038
```

::::: Trace ::::

```
--> Starting measurement...
<-- Measurement started
_sock_fd: -1963260928 
_sock_fd: 0x8afb0400
XCP: select() error 10038
```

:::::: Trace ::::

```
xcpApplication.exe -i 192.168.1.100 -p 5555

_sock_fd: 1936 _sock_fd: 0x790
successfully opened socket 192.168.1.100:5555

--> Connecting...
<-- Connection established
t
--> Setting daq signal list...
Sorting daq signal list...
Sorting done
<-- Daq signal list set
d
--> Configuring daq lists...
<-- Configuration done
c
--> Connecting...
<-- Connection established
r
--> Starting measurement...
<-- Measurement started
_sock_fd: 901186560 _sock_fd: 0x35b70400
XCP: select() error 10038
```

Comment: since you aren't using `write_fd` or `except_fd`, you can just pass `NULL` to `select()`.

Comment: Also, you are setting a timeout of `0`, which means you're just checking to see if any data is already available.  You could get the same behavior by setting the non-blocking mode on your socket and calling `recvfrom`.

Comment: the frequency of data received and passed on needs to be fast enough so i am using immeditate time out, or else the packets are lost due to overflow of the buffer.

Comment: That's not what the timeout does.

Comment: Source - MSDN Select function :
If TIMEVAL is initialized to {0, 0}, select will return immediately; this is used to poll the state of the selected sockets. If select returns immediately, then the select call is considered nonblocking and the standard assumptions for nonblocking calls apply.

Comment: But you said that helps you avoid overflow of the buffer -- it does not.  It's just wasting CPU time, since all you do is loop and call `select` immediately again.  And you could and should simply do a non-blocking read, since you aren't using the `writefds` or `exceptfds` capability of `select`.

Comment: @ Ben, thank you for the guidence.
Please do correct me if i am wrong, that could make it more appropiate but wont give the error of socket operation on nonsocket.
it seems the socket is closed and the select function tries to check the socket for the read_fd set.

Comment: Yes, that's why I used a comment rather than an answer to mention this.

Comment: Why do you say "connection established" when you are using a connection-less protocol (UDP)?

Comment: it is just a message, it has nothing to with connection oriented.

Answer (score 6):

```
>net helpmsg 10038

An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

You can safely close a socket in the TCP/IP sense, using the `shutdown()` function.  But don't call `closesocket()` on a `SOCKET` handle which is in use by `select()` or `poll()`.

Actually, in Win32 you will usually prefer to use `WSAAsyncSelect` or `WSAEventSelect` instead.

If your application is single-threaded and doesn't use asynchronous callbacks, then you can't call `closesocket` during the `select` call.  And I see that you return immediately after calling `closesocket`.  So you must be entering the function with an invalid socket, but `_isSocketOpen` is true.  Perhaps you should set that flag to false when calling `closesocket()`.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the handy `net helpmsg [errcode]` command!

Comment: I am using UDP/IP, the flag is reset by the close socket function.
i get this failure only with 1000 bytes / 0,5 msec if i decrease the size of data from 1000 bytes to 972 bytes it works perfectly fine. Some how in between 1000 to 972 bytes this error is reported.

Comment: Additional to the shutdown(), instead of closesocket(), this is executed only when the return value is SOCKET_ERROR. i am not sure if that can solve the error occured before. i am not sure if that has to do with memory leakage or so.

if i am wrong any way,any expert opinion ?

Comment: @Pipa's: What do you mean "the flag is reset by the close socket function?"  I see a call to `closesocket()` right there, and it doesn't modify `_isSocketOpen`.

Comment: @ Ben,
My appologies for sharing partial information...!!! Please find the close connection function eddited in the main blog.

Comment: @Pipa's: Even the new code you posted, shows that it is possible to close the socket without setting the `_isSocketOpen` flag to false.

Comment: @ Ben,
I tried debugging the code, the socket remains to be open, however the handle parameter (_sock_fd) refers a invalid socket.

_sock_fd should remain always valid.

Please see the debug trace.

Comment: @Pipa's: Can you add the value returned by `socket()` to your debug trace?  Printing handles in hexadecimal may be nicer as well.

Comment: "_sock_fd" is the return value from the socket().

Comment: @Pipa's: Yes I understand.  Can you print it immediately after the call to `socket()`, before any chance of memory corruption, and again when the error occurs?

Comment: @Ben,
yes i tried the same, the socket() reports no error, and as you can see in the trace, there is no error on the descriptor until the master send start measurement.
this descriptor error is only for 1000 bytes / sec, with increase / decrease than 1000 bytes/sec the descriptor remains always valid.

Comment: @Pipa's: But look -- the socket descriptor is `0x790`, but when the error occurs `_sock_fd` is filled with garbage.  The socket is not closed, but you are not passing a real socket to `select`.  I guess you have a buffer overflow nearby which is overwriting your socket handle.

Comment: @Pipa's: One thing you can do is put a data breakpoint on `_sock_fd` and see what function is changing it unexpectedly.

Comment: @ Ben,
Thank you very much for your help !!!!
I found the problem, it is with the Slave and not the master node for which this source code is. I tried all possible debuggings method but still could not find the problem. Then tested the same code with a simulated slave, and on this simulated test there was no failure reported. It seems that the physical slave has some problem and which results in the failure.

Comment: @Pipa's: You most certainly have an error which is allowing `_sock_fd` to be corrupted.  Although you may design your slave so that it doesn't encounter the error, you will be left with a security hole in your server.